# I have to write JUnit test case for service layer which uses ListIterator and returns list

Tags: mongodb, junit, listiterator, mongotemplate

Problem:
I have service method which returns list of objects in reverse order.
It is fetching list of objects from MongoDB using MongoTemplate,Query and uses ListIterator for reversing the list.

Now, I have to write JUnit test case for the above.

My present code where I am Mocking mongotemplate

```
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = Mockito.mock(MongoTemplate.class);
    Query query = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
    CRDetails crDetails = new CRDetails();
    CertificateGuidelines certG1 = new CertificateGuidelines("certG1", Constants.CERTIFICATION_TEAM, Constants.DOC_DEVELOPER_STATUS, 1);
    CertificateGuidelines certG2 = new CertificateGuidelines("certG2", Constants.DOCDEVELOPER, Constants.CERT_TEAM_STATUS, 2);
    CertificateGuidelines certG3 = new CertificateGuidelines("certG3", Constants.CERTIFICATION_TEAM, Constants.DOC_DEVELOPER_STATUS, 3);
    List<CertificateGuidelines> newHistoryList = new ArrayList<CertificateGuidelines>();
    newHistoryList.add(certG1);
    newHistoryList.add(certG2);
    newHistoryList.add(certG3);
    Mockito.when(mongoTemplate.findOne((org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query) Matchers.any(Query.class), Matchers.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(crDetails);

    CRService service = new CRService();
    service.setCertMongoTemplate(mongoTemplate);

assertEquals(historyList, newHistoryList);
```

My service method:

```
public List<CertificateGuidelines> getHistoryForCertGuidelines(String crNum) {
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("cr").is(crNum));
CRDetails details = certMongoTemplate.findOne(query, CRDetails.class,
        Constants.COLLECTION_NAME);
logger.debug("in history");

if (details != null) {
    logger.debug("Certification Guidelines has " + details.getCertGuidelinesList().size() + "previous updates");
}
List<CertificateGuidelines> historyList = new ArrayList<CertificateGuidelines>();

// Add objects to list.

// Generate an iterator. Start just after the last CG object.
ListIterator<CertificateGuidelines> listItr = details.getCertGuidelinesList().listIterator(
    details.getCertGuidelinesList().size());

// Iterate in reverse.
while (listItr.hasPrevious()) {
    historyList.add((CertificateGuidelines) listItr.previous());
}
return historyList;
    }
```

I know I am doing some mistake in writing test case. Not clear on how to approach. Please Guide.
Error Trace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<historyList> but was:<[com.cerner.docworks.domain.CertificateGuidelines@13805618, com.cerner.docworks.domain.CertificateGuidelines@56ef9176, com.cerner.docworks.domain.CertificateGuidelines@4566e5bd]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.cerner.docworks.service.test.CRServiceTest.testServiceHistoryDB(CRServiceTest.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are testing the equality of two lists, when what you really want to do is check that the lists contain the same elements.

The easiest way to do this is to use Hamcrest, which has the added advantage that it will show a better message in the event of failure.

```
Assert.assertThat(historyList,IsIterableContainingOrder.contains(newHistoryList.toArray()));
```